# how to calculate the percentage for each row in table in for given column in MySQL database using python

Tags: python, mysql

i have table presidents with 4 columns that is id,name,votes,percentage.given (1,2,3,4,5) are the ids,would like to calculate the percentage for each depending on the number of votes of each candidate. i tried this but it gives me an error that unsupported operand type(s) for / :'turple' and 'turple'. i be grateful if any one helps

`self.cursor.execute("""select sum(votes) from president""")
total=self.cursor.fetchall()[0]
for i in range(1,6):
    self.cursor.execute("""select votes from president where id = %s""",i)
    count = self.cursor.fetchone()[0]
    self.cursor.execute("""update presidents SET percentage = %s where id =%s""",((count/total),i))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`total` is being set to a tuple because you are using `fetchall`, which returns a list of row tuples. Use `fetchone` instead to fix that.

`cursor.execute` strictly requires a *tuple* as its second argument. The first call in your loop should therefore read

```
self.cursor.execute("""select count(votes) from president where id = %s""",(i, ))
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like both `count` and `total` contain a full row of results. Index into them with `[0]` one more time to get the values you need.